# Web2py import from csv

Tags: python, web2py

Is it possible import data from csv-file which contains values of primary keys instead their automatic creation? Primary keys of imported table are used as foreign keys in another table.

Comment: I've tried internal appadmin application, but didn't find needed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried importing a CSV with primary key values. But I was in similar situation (primary keys of some table used as foreign key in other tables)

I think it is risky/error prone to put the keys in CSV. What I ended up doing was write a script to read the CSV and then using "db..insert". Cache the ID returned by insert statement and use it when inserting the secondary table.

I hope this makes sense.